# Does the generalised directional derivative satisfy any version of the chain rule?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-calculus, generalized-jacobians

Is there a chain rule of any kind for the generalised directional derivative (of the Clarke type)? There is certainly a chain rule for the generalised gradient.

The generalised directional derivative is: $$f^\circ(x;v)=\limsup_{y \to x, t \downarrow 0} \frac{f(y+tv) - f(y)}{t},$$
where $x,v \in \mathbb R^n$ for some $n$, and $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. Albeit, the definition is valid over any Banach space (but I'd like to keep things to finite dimensions for simplicity's sake).

Some information about it can be found here: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Clarke_generalized_derivative

[edit]

The naive version of the chain rule is false: Consider $f(x) = |x|, g(x) = -x$. We have that $(f\circ g)^\circ(0;1) = 1$ while $f^\circ(g(0); g^\circ(0;1)) = f^\circ(0;-1) = -1$. What I'm looking for must therefore be an inequality.

Comment: Please provide some context. Are you working in an arbitrary Banach space?

Comment: @YCor $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: What is the point of the variable $y$ in the definition?

Comment: a typo, $x$ in the numerator on the right-hand-side should read $y$

Comment: So if $m=n=1$ and $f$ is a function whose slope alters between $+1$ and $-1$ faster and faster as $x$ goes to zero, we get that $f^\circ(0)=1$ since close to one, there is always a point with slope $+1$ and we get $(-f)^\circ(0)=1$, since the same is true for $-f$. Doesnt that contradict the chai rule

Comment: @CarloBeenakker thank you

Comment: @HenrikRüping It could be an inequality instead. Basically, the generalised gradient already satisfies only a weak version of the chain rule

Comment: It may be helpful if you can quote in your question the known weak version of the chain rule satisfied by the generalized gradient.

Answer (score 1):

According to theorem 8.14 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04180.pdf, we have that for locally Lipschitz $g:Y\to \mathbb R$ and Frechet-differentiable $f: X \to Y$, that

$$(g\circ f)^\circ(x;v) \leq g^\circ(f(x);f'(x)v).$$

Equality holds if $g$ is *regular.*

We can furthermore say that:

$$(g\circ f)^\circ(x;v) \geq -g^\circ(f(x);-f'(x)v)$$
under the same conditions.

Answer (score 0):

A nice and non-trivial extension of the chain-rule occurs from the DiPerna-Lions theory of rough vector fields: take on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$ a vector field $X$ with $L^\infty_{loc}(\Omega)$ coefficients and null divergence such that $X\in W^{1,1}_{loc}(\Omega)$. Let $u$ be an $L^\infty_{loc}(\Omega)$ function such that $Xu\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. Then 
$$
X(u^2)=2u Xu.
$$
The previous chain-rule formula is the main point to prove uniqueness of weak solutions for these vector fields. There are generalizations in several directions: instead of looking at $u^2$, you may check
$$
X(F(u))=F'(u) Xu, \quad F\in C^1.
$$
Also, you can relax the regularity $W^{1,1}$ to $BV$, play a bit with regularity $W^{1,p}$ and relax as well the condition on the divergence by requiring only absolute continuity wrt Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the question in the OP. Can you give more details?

Comment: Well the chain rule is about finding the derivative of $F\circ u$. My remark above is highlighting the fact that when you have a limited amount of regularity, say when the function $u$ is not better than $L^\infty$, if you have the weak information that $Xu$ belongs to $L^1$, you can still apply the chain rule and this is the core argument for the DiPerna-Lions theory  for first-order linear equations with $W^{1,1}$ coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Even for finite-dimension, you have only an inclusion instead of equality in the chain rule. Basically, naively performing the chain rule by multiplying Clarke subdifferentials can result in a set that strictly contains the Clarke subdifferential of the composition. This is made clear in the book of Clarke.

If you want something *like* the Clarke subdifferential which admits a chain rule by design, I invite you to read about [conservative fields](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-020-01501-5).

Answer (score -1):

The straightforward generalization of the [usual chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Chain_rule) would give 
$$(f\circ g)^\circ(x,v)=v\cdot\bigl(Dg(x)\bigr)^{\rm T}\cdot\bigl(\nabla f(y)\bigr),$$
with $Dg$ the Jacobian matrix and $g(x)=y$.

Comment: except I don't think that's true...

Comment: consider $f(x) = |x|$, $g(x) = -|x|$, $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$. We have $f^\circ(0;1) = 1$, $g^\circ(0;1) = 1$, while $h^\circ(0;1) = 0$. This contradicts the addition rule, and therefore your naive version of the chain rule

Comment: I may edit the question to include these examples

Comment: I've included a simple example in the question